# Finding similar images with different intensities/brightness

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

Suppose I have images as follows:

[image]

[image]

What would be my options to compare the similarity between the two images? Obviously they are the same image just with different brightness. I couldn't find any plausible way for this and currently my best bet would be to train a cnn or autoencoder and compare the feature vectors of the outputs, but that just seems a bit overkill for this. Any tips would be appreciated.

Comment: Not sure about any existing solutions, but in general I think it would be a good idea to simply compare the two images in the HSL (hue, saturation, lightness) color space. If they only differ in brightness I would assume the H and S values would be the same, or at least very similar.

Comment: Indeed they would only differ in brightness. Thanks!

Comment: image normalization might be a good preprocessing

Comment: SSIM See https://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/auto_examples/transform/plot_ssim.html and https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2014/09/15/python-compare-two-images/

Comment: You could also compare the image edges, they should be mostly identical depending on the parameterization, even with different brightness.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty robust working solution (I tested) is to check correlation of brightness sign changes between pixels.

I.e. assuming images A and B, loop for significant number of pixels:

```
IF (
  (brightness of pixel 1 from A IS LARGER than brightness of pixel 2 from A)
  AND
  (brightness of pixel 1 from B IS LARGER than brightness of pixel 2 from B)
) {
  COUNTER++;
}
```

And vice versa for opposite relationship. The higher the COUNTER the more similar are the images.

IMPORTANT: I tested the method on (inter-area) scaled-down images, not full size, as full size images may contain some compression artifacts. My intuition suggests it will work on full size images anyway, just with a different threshold. If not, resize by area to preserve well average brightness values (similar to INTER_AREA in OpenCV), and it will do the trick.

Related ideas can be found at [image comparison algorithm](https://vitali-fedulov.github.io/similar.pictures/algorithm-for-perceptual-image-comparison.html).

Comment: If I understood correctly you suppose that one should loop through all the pixels on the image and compute the correlation between i and i+1 pixels on each image and increase the counter if the conditions are both satisfied?

Comment: Yes (in the simplest approach). It is possible to loop through all pixel pairs, but not necessary, as the number of each-to-each image pixel pairs can be very large. The probability of images being similar gets flatter after some large, but not too large, number of pixel pairs. Randomly chosen positions should do too, provided they are identical for both compared images.